# match the strings with rectangular brackets in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to use "regexp" for some string checking. Code 1 worked, but it failed if $ref is from a file. Below is the code:

Code 1 works fine:

```
set foo "input \[1:0\]"
regexp {input \[} $foo
```

Code 2, $ref is from file:

##ref_file contain this string:

input [

Code:

```
set foo "input \[1:0\]"
set fi [open ref_file r]
gets $fi ref
regexp $ref $foo
```

I can't control the ref_file. How to make this code work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you are using any of the things that regexp matching provides and doing only normal string comparison... so why not just use something like [`string first`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M8)?

```
set foo "input \[1:0\]"
string first {input [} $foo
```

`string first` returns the index of the match, and an index of `-1` means no match was found. You can easily use this in an `if` like this:

```
if {[string first $ref $foo] > -1} {
    ...
}
```

---

If you're still intent on using regexp, then I guess you could use a helper proc to escape non-word characters:

```
proc regesc {text} {
    regsub -all {\W} $text {\\&}
}

set foo "input \[1:0\]"
set fi [open ref_file r]
gets $fi ref
regexp [regesc $ref] $foo
```